# Did Amara know what she was saying to Viktoria?

Tags: pacific-rim-uprising

Early on in *Pacific Rim: Uprising*, after Amara first clashes with Viktoriya, one of the other cadets offers to teach Amara a few words of Russian "to help you get along with her", or something to that effect. Later on in the film, when they get into another argument, the following exchange occurs:

> **Amara**: [*in Russian*] Kiss my ass.
>   **Viktoriya**: What did you say?!
>   **Amara**: [*in Russian*] Kiss my ass. [*in English, to the other cadet*] Am I saying that right?
>   [*Viktoriya attacks her*]

There are two possible interpretations of this scene:

1. Amara knew *exactly* what that phrase meant and was deliberately trying to rile Viktoriya up.
2. The other cadet tricked her when he taught her that phrase, and Amara thought she was saying something that would defuse the situation. (This was my initial interpretation of the scene.)

**Which interpretation is correct?** Was Amara knowingly telling Viktoriya to kiss her ass, or was it a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by her expression and reaction, I think it very unlikely that Amara knew what she was saying. It was made fairly clear that she was trying to integrate, at that point anyway, and it would have been against her motivation to be deliberately antagonistic.

Obviously this is my interpretation, as I have no confirmation of this via script or outside interview.